# How do I solve net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR error when I put nginx in front of Tomcat?

Tags: nginx, tomcat, server, backend, was

How do I fix net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR error when I put nginx in front of Tomcat?

```
#user nobody;
worker_processes 1;

#error_log logs/error.log;
#error_log logs/error.log notice;
#error_log logs/error.log info;

#pid logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}


http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    #log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    # '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    # '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log logs/access.log main;

    sendfile on;
    #tcp_nopush on;

    #keepalive_timeout 0;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    upstream tomcat {
        server 127.0.0.1:8330;
    }

    charset utf-8;



    #gzip on;

    server {
        listen 8331;
        server_name localhost;

        # return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log logs/host.access.log main;

        location / {
            # root html;
            # index index.html index.htm;
            # proxy_pass http://sgmng.pluggolf.com;

            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Origin "";
            # new

            # Copy the upstream path set above
            proxy_pass https://tomcat;
            # proxy_redirect off;
            charset utf-8;
        }

        #error_page 404 /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        # proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        # root html;
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # fastcgi_index index.php;
        # fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        # include fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        # deny all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    # server {
    # listen 8080;
    # listen somename:8080;
    # server_name somename alias another.alias;

    # location / {
    # root html;
    # index index.html index.htm;
    # }
    # }


    # HTTPS server
    
    server {
       listen 8332 ssl;
       server_name localhost;

       charset utf-8;

       ssl_certificate D:/service/cbdc_dt/nginx/cert/plusity.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key D:/service/cbdc_dt/nginx/cert/plusity.key;

    # ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    # ssl_session_timeout 5m;

       ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

       location / {
        # root html;
        # index index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass http://tomcat;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            # proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection '';
        proxy_set_header Origin "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        chunked_transfer_encoding off;

        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_cache off;
        proxy_read_timeout 7d;
        proxy_redirect off;
        charset utf-8;
       }
    }

}
```

After applying ssl to all requests coming to ports 8331 and 8332 as follows, I wrote a code that redirects to port 8330 of tomcat.

However, the problem is that if you go to 8330 through nginx like this, `GET https://serverIP:8330/itf/subscribe net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error occurs.

/itf/subscribe works normally when nginx is not present.

But there seems to be a problem when calling from within the address of https.

I am wondering how can I solve that problem.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

> However, the problem is that if you go to 8330 through nginx like this, GET https://serverIP:8330/itf/subscribe net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR error occurs.

Port 8330 is served by Tomcat, not Nginx. Hence the protocol error.  You currently have Nginx listening on:

- `http://localhost:8331   ->  http://127.0.0.1:8330`
- `https://localhost:8332  ->  http://127.0.0.1:8330`